# Vagrantでホストからゲストに通信が出来ない。

Tags: network, http, vagrant, virtualbox, ipアドレス

**使用しているソフトバージョン**
Vagrant 2.2.4
VirtualBox バージョン 5.2.28 r130011 (Qt5.6.3)
VBoxControl バージョン　5.2.28r130011
ホストos mac High Sierra 10.13.5
ゲストos Ubuntu14.04

**vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  #ここで公式サイトからOSのイメージをダウンロードしている。 
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/home/vagrant"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.

end
```

**状態**

ホストで`lsof -i :8080`コマンドを入力するとリスニングしているのが確認できる。

```
VBoxHeadl 577 development   17u  IPv4 xxxxxxxxxxxx      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

ゲスト側はhttp://localhost:8080でサーバを立てている。`netstat -anp`コマンドで確認すると`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1349/python`
と表示されListen状態である。

**問題**
ホストからSSHでゲストにアクセスできる。
ホストからhttpリクエストを投げると拒否される。
ホストから`curl http://127.0.0.1:8080`
に投げると`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`と返ってくる。
なぜ上手くポートフォワードされないのでしょうか？
ゲストサーバを0.0.0.0にするとできるのですが、これは全てのIPv4からのアクセスを受け付けてしまうのでなるべく使わない方が良いのではないかと考えています。

どなたか詳しい方教えていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ポートフォワードしても`127.0.0.1`(`localhost`)へは到達できないためです。
`127.0.0.1`は自身(この場合VM内)からしかアクセスできません。

＃ホストOSの`127.0.0.1`とゲストOSの`127.0.0.1`は別物です。

＃VirtualBoxでポートフォワードしてアクセスする場合、NATされたアドレスをソースIPとして、ゲストOSのDHCPで割り当てたアドレスにアクセスするはずです。(そのアドレスではListenしていないので「`Connection reset by peer`」となる次第です)

ホストOSからのアクセスだけ許可したいのであれば、「ホストオンリーアダプタ」(`private network)に

割り当てられたIPアドレス(上記設定の場合、`192.168.33.11`)でListenし、そこに対し、`curl`等で
アクセスすればよいと思います。

Comment: このプライベートネットワークをホストと同じipにすると127.0.0.1でもアクセスできるようになるのでしょうか？

Comment: ホストネットワークと同じIPにしても、ホストOSからゲストOSの`127.0.0.1`にはアクセスできません。(そもそも同一ネットワーク(セグメント)内に同一のIPアドレスは配置できません)

Comment: 分かりました。ありがとうござます。